Can't test React Idle Timer's useIdleTimer hook when inside a custom hook
In a react app, I have a custom hook which calls useIdleTimer docs here, amongst other things.
I'd like to have a test which checks that onIdle is called after the timeout expires.
However, onIdle never appears to be called during the test, but works in when this app runs in the browser.
Here's a repro
I have tried various methods of changing the test time (advanceTimersByTime, setSystemTime, etc) and have logged out some of the values. I've noticed that getLastIdleTime()  always returns null, which may be part of the problem. Maybe JSDom isn't passing one of the libraries checks?
